# Why does this query a key lookup?

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan, sql-optimization

I am trying to understand why does this query a key lookup, even if I added all columns i am selecting in the index?

Here's the query

```
SELECT TOP 1
    ART.Id, 
    ART.Title, 
    ART.InitialTitle, 
    ART.Summary,
    ART.IsCategoryFirst,
    ART.RootCategoryId, 
    CAT.Name, 
    ART.OldFacebookCommentsUrl, 
    ICO.CssClass,
    ART.TopicName, 
    ART.MainArticlePhoto, 
    ART.FrontPagePhoto, 
    ART.PublishDate
FROM Articles ART WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN Categories CAT WITH (NOLOCK) ON CAT.Id = ART.RootCategoryId 
LEFT JOIN ArticleIcons ICO WITH (NOLOCK) ON ICO.Id = ART.IconId
WHERE ART.RootCategoryId = 3
  AND ART.PublishDate < GETDATE() 
  AND ART.Active = 1
  AND IsCategoryFirst = 1
```

Here is the index which should cover it

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [SmallArticleResponse] ON [dbo].[Articles]
(
    [RootCategoryId] ASC,
    [Active] ASC,
    [PublishDate] DESC,
    [Coefficient] DESC
)
INCLUDE (   [Id],
    [Title],
    [InitialTitle],
    [OldFacebookCommentsUrl],
    [Summary],
    [IconId],
    [TopicName],
    [FrontPagePhoto],
    [MainArticlePhoto],
    [FacebookPhoto],
    [IsCategoryFirst]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

This is execution plan and info for it.
[image: Execution plan]
[image: Key lookup info]

Comment: Because IsCategoryFirst column isn't in the key, most likely. Or conversely, because there is a separate index on it (single column?) and it's using that instead.

Comment: that would be it. silly me

Comment: a little offtopic: you may find interesting this post about `with (nolock)` clause - https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Which one was it?

Comment: @BradleyUffner Gareth had correct answer. He may type it, so i can mark it as a solution :)

Comment: @Robert Yeah, but he gave you 2 possibilities.  Was it using a different index, or was it because `IsCategoryFirst` wasn't in the key?

Comment: @BradleyUffner kinda both. It's definitely using the other index, as it's in the plan. But adding the IsCategoryFirst to the key should mean it starts using the covering index. Dropping the IsCategoryFirst index would probably also cause the covering index to be used but may not be desirable overall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because IsCategoryFirst column isn't in the key, most likely. And/or because there is a separate (single column?) index on IsCategoryFirst and it's using that instead.

Comment: Apparently it is using different index because of order by clause. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: There's no order by clause in your posted query

Comment: i am sorry, i was debugging different query later on.